# How do i link css and js in wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to code a wordpress plugin for a chatbot. But when I try to load the css and js for this plugin I always get this error:

**Error Console Screenshot:**

[image]

Both the css and js are in a seperate folder in the plugin folder called "/css/bot.css" and "/js/chatbot.js"
I tried to link them with wp_enque_style and wp_enque_scripts

**Code Screenshot**:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you console is complaining of `chatbot.css` not loading, but your code is queueing `bot.css`.  So is the chatbot.css/chatobot.js console errors related to other files?  Can you revert back with the 404 error details URL paths the browser is complaining about.

Comment: Instead of posting a screen capture of your enqueue code, next time just paste the enqueue code here... ...if someone wants to assist you now you're forcing them to manually re-type all your code in their answer rather than cutting and pasting before making the corrections.